# C++ Gin Rummy not Removing From Vector

Tags: c++11, unix

Currently I am programming Gin Rummy in C++11 and when dealing out cards my deck removes cards initially so the player gets a real like hand but when moving to dealing cards to the next player it gives that player the same Cards.
Here is a link to a github repo which contains my files. I will attach the output. If you wish to compile the code please you the ./compile script, it contains the necessary files and excludes the table.cpp. This is the output

Github Repo: [Gin Rummy](http://github.com/lgarceau/GIN-RUMMY)

[image: Output]

Currently I am not including table.cpp to table.h to be compilied.
I am confused on why it is not removing the Card objects from the Deck vector.

Deck.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "deck.h"
#include "card.h"

using namespace std;

//Addes 52 cards to the deck
Deck::Deck() {
    cardsInDeck = {};
}    
//Remove top card from deck
Card Deck::drawCard(){ 
    Card topCard = getCards()[cardsInDeck.size()-1];
    popCard();
    getCards().shrink_to_fit();
    vector<Card> c2 = getCards();
    int size = getCards().size();
    cout << size << endl;
    return topCard;
}

void Deck::popCard(){
    this->cardsInDeck.pop_back();
}    
//Add card to a deck
void Deck::addCard(Card addedCard) {
    this->cardsInDeck.push_back(addedCard);
}      
vector<Card> Deck::getCards(){
    return cardsInDeck;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <ctime>
#include "player.h"
#include "deck.h"
#include "card.h"
#include "computer.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));



    Deck testDeck;
    testDeck.newDeck();
    testDeck.shuffleDeck();
    cout << testDeck.deckSize() <<endl;
    //testDeck.displayCards();
    //cout << endl << endl;

    Player player1;
    player1.firstHand(testDeck);
    player1.showHand();
    cout << endl << testDeck.deckSize() << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;


    Player player2;
    player2.firstHand(testDeck);
    player2.showHand();
    cout << endl << testDeck.deckSize() << endl;

    return 0;   

};
```

Comment: Any suggestions, ideas, or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your code in the question.

Comment: The output for player 1 is cut off but is identical to the output of player two, the one below it.

Comment: Emphasis on the **minimal**:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Any better @DerekBrown

Comment: No, isolate down to exactly where your problem is arising

Comment: How about that?

Comment: Educated guess: `Player::firstHand` takes `Deck` by value.